# How to enable --harmony-proxies in gulp-mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

How can I enable `--harmony-proxies` in gulp-mocha? I need to use `--harmony-proxies`so when I run some unit tests I don't get the following error:

```
TypeError: Proxy is not a function
```